# How do I do a Global Update in Firebase?

Tags: firebase

I'm trying to wrap my head around firebase, and one issue I can't seem to work out is how mass updates occur.

Lets say I have 1,000 users and they all have "user_role": "member"

And I decide to update all 1,000 users to "user_role":"paid-member"

in SQL I can just do UPDATE users SET user_role = 'paid-member' ...  So what's the Firebase equivalent?

Or more importantly, how would I accomplish something like this in firebase...

UPDATE users SET user_role = 'paid-member' WHERE user_role = 'member'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to do this without knowing the list of users beforehand. If you had all the usernames in an array, you could do something like this:

```js
var usernames = [...];
for (var i = 0; i < usernames.length; i++) {
  var ref = new Firebase("https://myfirebase.firebaseio.com/users/" + usernames[i]);
  ref.child("user_role").set("paid-member");
}
```

You'll have to retrieve the list of usernames first using a `child_added` or `value` event handler.